# gTLD registering periods?

Tags: dns, tld

I'm just reading up on the gTLDs and it seems the application closed in June 2012.
On the ICANN website (Which is a UX nightmare), there is no sign of if/when the application procedure will re-open, does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irony! - ICANN finally replied to my e-mail not 5 minutes after I posted this question. Just for anyone eleses reference, here's their response:

```
Thank you for your email and interest in the New gTLD Program.

You are correct, the application window for New gTLDs has closed.

No dates have been set for the next application round. Please monitor our website at newgtlds.icann.org for updates and announcements regarding the next application round.

You can also participate in the Program through Program processes such as Application Comments. Please visit our website at newgtlds.icann.org and http://www.icann.org/en/about/participate/how to learn about how to participate in the New gTLD Program and ICANN's processes, respectively.

Best regards,

New gTLD Customer Service`
```